# Maui partial class false compiler errors that do not prevent build and deploy

Tags: compiler-errors, maui, partial-classes, codemaid

```
Partial method 'PlatformSpecificHelper.Close()' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.
```

I am getting an error like this for every single method in my Static helper class, but it does not prevent compilation, building and deployment, and the methods all work as intended. It is like the (not too uncommon) intellisense errors, which goes away on their own, except these do not go away, though they also do no real harm.

I have a partial class defined in main maui code as well as in the platform specific folders.
A simplified example is
General code:

```
namespace Util;
public static partial class PlatformSpecificHelper
{
    public static partial void Close();
```

Android code (ios looks the same):

```
namespace Util;
public static partial class PlatformSpecificHelper
{
    public static partial void Close()
    {
        try
        {........
```

I tried deleting the bin and obj files in the project folder and then the errors are gone on restart, but come back after a little bit, when project is reinitialized. Cleaning and rebuilding does not remove them.

I saw others having (different) issues with partial classes and codemaid. I am actually using codemaid, so I disabled it, deleted bin and obj and restarted and it seemed to fix it. Then I turned it back on and off to verify, and then it did no difference (errors popped up) . So, it is probably not related.

Again, this code looks right, and it works perfectly, but I am getting spammed with 19 errors like the one mentioned, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Even though maui is a single project, is it really considered the same assembly? That is the base requirement for partial class, but I don't think it applies here. If you believe it does, this merits opening a ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: I know that it works in practise, and that calling native code through partial classes is an idea I got from a "learn with microsoft" guide, I found somewhere some time previously. I am pretty sure this is supposed to work... as it does. It just gives "wrong" compiler messages, so... "something else" is up.

Comment: I myself think your scenario can be solved by moving to DI with platform providers and a shared interface to register them with. In your csproj, do you perhaps include both platform's implementation at the same time perhaps?

Comment: Does running code-maid delete your empty methods? If so just throw a not implemented exception from it

Comment: Changing to the usual system with shared interfaces would work, but I really like the simplicity of the partial classes, and it is supposed to work without odd errors, so therefore that was the issue i wanted to try solving first.
As to codemaid deleting things, it does not visibly, and I think it may be innocent, and there were just an odd chain of events related to removing it.